# Codeigniter css disappearance

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have a controller in codeigniter by the name of Home, and the code looks as such:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {  
    public function index() {
         $this->load->view('foundation_css');
         $this->load->view('topbar');
         $this->load->view('home_page');
    }
}
```

The foundation_css view contains the foundation css linked, the topbar view contains html that displays a topbar, and the home_page view constructs the basic home page.

This is how the page looks when the url I access is `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php`.

[image]

This is how the page looks when the url I access is `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/home/`.

[image]

Why does the CSS disappear when the url changes? Does url with which I access the css file change? if so, how would I remedy the situation? For further information, the url I use is `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.min.css">`. The tree of files looks as such:

```
/
    css/
        -foundation.min.css
    application/
        controllers/
            home.php
        views/
            foundation_css.php
            topbar.php
            home_page.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Use full link for css files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url();?>path_to_css_folder/css/foundation.min.css">
```

The main reson is bacause when you change url to /home/ it's like subdirectory for server and he can't found your css folder.

Comment: Thank you! However, when I tried that, from both urls the pages turned blank. Is there any reason why that may be? I changed it to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url();?>css/foundation.min.css">`  
  
I checked the page source, and it said that the function was undefined. Where would it be defined?

Comment: I think in config/autoload.php you must load 'url' helper
`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` // line 67.
ALTERNATIVE - You can change `<?=base_url();?>` with `http://domain.com/'

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/zSCGsdAw) is my autoload file, [this](http://pastebin.com/D4YndTT8) is the view file that I include in [the controller](http://pastebin.com/YfX9YX67). I'm not sure where it's crashing or why it's crashing. I have tried `<?=base_url();?>` as well.

Comment: @Swarage, See my code. You use `$this->base_url()` now, but I told you to use only '`base_url()'

Comment: Even then the css doesn't show. The overall path ends up being `/css/foundation.min.css` but the css doesn't show. if the path I'm on is `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php`, what should the url of the css be.

Comment: Thank you! That works, but I'd like to use the base_url option. Given the tree I posted above, why does the path `/css/foundation.min.css/` not work?

Comment: don't use first slash. only `<?php echo base_url();?>css/foundation.min.css`

Comment: I understand that. In the config file I make base_url() return "/". I'm wondering why that raw url won't work.

Answer (score 1):

simply use something like this in your file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->base_url();?>css/foundation.min.css">
```

You have to load the `url helper class` in `controller` where you call the view part something like

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('foundation_css');
```

link of [url helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)